# converting regular javascript implementation to ruby on rails javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have the following code in a regular index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>

  <body>

  <!-- A BUNCH OF OTHER CODE..... -->

    <!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT ! -->

    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--BACKSTRETCH-->
    <!-- You can use an image of whatever size. This script will stretch to fit in any screen size.-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch("assets/img/solar.jpg", {speed: 500});
    </script>

    <!-- END OF WHAT I WANT -->


  </body>
</html>
```

At the end of the index.html, I want to incorporate the jquery javascript and the jquery-backstretch.min file into my rails application. Is there a standard rails way of doing this?

I've tried to inject the following into a rails new.html.erb

```
<!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<%= javascript_include_tag '../assets/javascripts/jquery.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<!--BACKSTRETCH-->
<!-- You can use an image of whatever size. This script will stretch to fit in any screen size.-->
<%= javascript_include_tag '../assets/javascripts/jquery.backstretch.min.js"', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<script>
    $.backstretch("assets/images/solar.jpg", {speed: 500});
</script>
```

and

```
<!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>

<!--BACKSTRETCH-->
<!-- You can use an image of whatever size. This script will stretch to fit in any screen size.-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.backstretch("assets/images/solar.jpg", {speed: 500});
</script>
```

but unfortunately both of them appears to be wrong.

What should I do?

EDIT:

I've added the modified files to my application.js so now it looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.backstretch.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and I've since then removed the corresponding script tags from new.html.erb. Now, at the bottom, it only contains the script call

```
<script>
    $.backstretch("assets/images/solar.jpg", {speed: 500});
</script>
```

but unfortunately that is still incorrect

Comment: Does jQuery is set at the bottom? Maybe the issue is from `backstrectch` script.

Comment: hmm I am not sure what you mean. Should i move the jquery to the top?

Comment: When you call `$.backstretch`, does `$` is set?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that you might be able to use. The javascript for the backstretch plugin is working with this method. I'm currently using it on one page since backstretch will fire off on all pages if you add the require statement and javascript for the method to the application.js file.

Step #1 One install the gem backstretch-rails
Step #2 Remove //= require backstretch
Step #3 add `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.backstretch" %>`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "backstretch-landing-index" %>
```

to your index.html.erb view. top of the body tag

Step #4 add

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.backstretch.js )
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( backstretch-landing-index.js )
```

to your initializers/assets.rb file

Inside of the backstretch-landing-index.js Add the function that you want to call

```
$.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

It works!! with the full path link of the image. `"/assets/photo1.png"` for me